# iOS Obj-C - UITableView data disappears when modal view dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview inside of a view controller, and a button underneath of my uitableview. Tapping this button opens a modal view. I've created a "close" button inside my modal using the following code:

**modalview.m**

```
- (IBAction)closeButton:(id)sender {

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However when I tap to dismiss my modal view, all of the data in my uitableview seems to disappear (the uitableview just goes white)? Any idea why this might be, and how can I fix it? Here is how my tableview data is loaded and structured (hope this helps):

**ViewController.m**

```
    -(void)updateMessages {

        self.tableView.dataSource = self;

        NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams setValue:@"name" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


            self.messages = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;

            [self.tableView reloadData];


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];



    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

       [self updateMessages];

       static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
       static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";


        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier bundle:nil];
        [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier];

        UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName: ChatTableIdentifier2 bundle:nil];
        [self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier: ChatTableIdentifier2];


          self.tableView.dataSource = self;

         [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    - (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

    {
        return 1;

    }


    - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        return [self.messages count];


    }



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.row];

        id swaptime = data[@"swaptime"];
        if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            // There is a valid "swaptime" value
            static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";

            SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *time = data[@"swaptime"];
            cell.startTime.text = time;

            NSString *timeEnd = data[@"endswaptime"];
            cell.endTime.text = timeEnd;

            NSString *costofSwap = data[@"swapvalue"];
            cell.swapValue.text = costofSwap;

            NSString *fromUsername = data[@"first name"];
            cell.fromUser.text = fromUsername;

            NSString *pet = data[@"pet's name"];
            cell.petsname.text = pet;


            NSString *swapStatus = data[@"swapaccepted"];

            if ([swapStatus isEqual: @"Yes"]) {

            [cell.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenbar.png"]];

                cell.swapTitle.text = @"Accepted!";}


            else {

                if ([swapStatus isEqual: @""]) {

                    [cell.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangecellbar.png"]];

                    cell.swapTitle.text = @"You have a Request!";}

                if ([swapStatus isEqual: @"Requested"]) {

                    [cell.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangecellbar.png"]];

                    cell.swapTitle.text = @"You have a Request!";}

                if ([swapStatus isEqual: @"Cancelled"]) {

                    [cell.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueecellbar.png"]];

                    cell.swapTitle.text = @"Cancelled!";}

                if ([swapStatus isEqual: @"No"]) {

                    [cell.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbar.png"]];

                    cell.swapTitle.text = @"Declined!";


            }


          }

            return cell;

        } else {
            static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";

            ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *userName = data[@"first name"];
            cell.sendingUser.text = userName;

            NSString *messageBody = data[@"body"];
            cell.messageDisplayed.text = messageBody;

            NSString *timeReceived = data[@"published at"];
            cell.timeStamp.text = timeReceived;


            NSString *userInfo = [self.userid objectForKey:@"first name"];


            if ([cell.sendingUser.text isEqual: userInfo]) {

                cell.messageDisplayed.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                cell.sendingUser.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


                [cell.chatBubble setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubblegrey2.png"]];


            } else {

             cell.messageDisplayed.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
             cell.sendingUser.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;


                [cell.chatBubble setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleorange2.png"]];

            }

            return cell;
        }
    }

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];


}
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`? Or anything that affect tableView from your modal? Try add background color to your table view and see if its still there or gone

Comment: @Tj3n See edit above for what's in viewDidAppear. I've made it so that when user lands in this view, it automatically scrolls all of the way to the bottom of the tableview. Would the code I've used effect this?

Comment: Why are you setting the table view's content offset to such a large value? What is your goal with that line?

Comment: Check the value of data source (self.messages) after dismissing the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your `viewDidAppear`, try replace:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

with:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.messages count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

or properly calculate the height, probably it's:

```
self.tableView.contentView.height
```

Comment: Replacing the line with the one you suggested causes a crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).